# How to evaluate xpath for a specific namesapce using phpstorm?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, settings, phpstorm

The European Central Bank offers a [XML document for currency exchange rates](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) dependent from the euro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2015-09-17'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.1312'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='136.76'/>
            <Cube currency='BGN' rate='1.9558'/>
            ...
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I have stored this XML file as a testcase for a currency rate provider, as I wanted to write a parser for it.

I wanted to use phpstorm's `Evaluate XPath...` feature.

Yet it didn't seem to recognize the namespace; so it did not find any match for `//Cube`.

[image: Evaluate XPath window]

I also tried using `Show unique XPath`, and for me it displays

`/gesmes:Envelope/e:Cube/e:Cube/e:Cube/@rate`

Yet using this for evaluating yields in no repsonse.

I guess I have it malconfigured (as I tried to edit the context, yet I did not know what I was doing).

[image: Edit Xpath Context]

How do I setup the correct namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the prefix `e` for the namespace `http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref` in the Xpath expression but configured the prefix `c` for it.

You don't need to write a parser for it in PHP. Just use DOM + Xpath.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('gesmes', 'http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01');
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref');

$time = $xpath->evaluate('string(/gesmes:Envelope/e:Cube/e:Cube/@time)');

$rates = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/gesmes:Envelope/e:Cube/e:Cube/e:Cube') as $cube) {
  $rates[$cube->getAttribute('currency')] = $cube->getAttribute('rate');
}

var_dump($time, $rates);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "2015-09-22"
array(31) {
  ["USD"]=>
  string(6) "1.1155"
  ["JPY"]=>
  string(6) "133.75"
  ["BGN"]=>
  string(6) "1.9558"
  ["CZK"]=>
  string(6) "27.057"
  ["DKK"]=> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell XPath what namespaces are bound to what prefixes, or set a default namespace for unprefixed names in your expression. Not all host languages support setting this.

In PHPStorm, you can do this by clicking on button <kbd>Edit context...</kbd>, [see documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/xpath-expression-evaluation.html#xpath-context).

If, for some reason, you cannot set this properly, you can use a query using the local name of a name<sup>⑴</sup>, your query then becomes:

```
/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']
    /*[local-name() = 'Cube']
    /*[local-name() = 'Cube']
    /*[local-name() = 'Cube']/@rate
```

Not ideal, but it will work.

<sub>⑴ Any XML name contains a local part, which is the part after the colon or the whole name if there is no colon, a prefix part, which is the part before the colon, and the namespace part, which is the namespace the prefix is bound to. An XML name is deterministically defined by it local-name and its namespace, the prefix does not matter.</sub>